# How can I print out the record of specific staff using vector in C++?

Tags: c++

For the task, there are 4 staffs and each staff has own work record. How can I save the work record to that specific staff and print it out using vector?

For example, the second staff has 2 works to do and others don't have any.

Then I have to print:

First Staff: No Work Found!

Second Staff: Work 1:xxxxx
              Work 2:xxxxx

Third Staff: No Work Found!

Forth Staff: No Work Found!

I am a C++ beginner. I hope someone could give some tips.

Edit:

What I have done so far:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    class Staff{
    private:
        string name;
        vector <Staff> sList;
    public:
        Staff(string n){
            name=n;

        }
        string getName(){

            return name;
        }
    };
    class Record{
        string recDate;
        string title;
    public:
        Record(string date, string t){
            date=recDate;
            t=title;

        }
        string getDate(){

            return recDate;
        }
        string getTitle(){

            return title;
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        vector<Staff> List;
        string name;
        cout<<"Enter name"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            cin>>name;
            Staff s(name);
            List.push_back(s);

        }

        cout<<"Staff List"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<List.size();i++){

            cout<<i+1<<". "<<List[i].getName()<<endl;
        }
        int staffnumber;
        string date, title;
        cout<<"Enter number "<<endl;
        cin>>staffnumber;
        cout<<"Enter date"<<endl;
        cin>>date;
        cout<<"enter title"<<endl;
        cin>>title;

        Record rec(date,title);
        int numS;
        cout<<"Staff List"<<endl;
           for(int i=0;i<List.size();i++){

               cout<<i+1<<". "<<List[i].getName()<<endl;
           }
        cout<<"Who you want to check"<<endl;
        cin>>numS;
    }
```

There is one question I want to ask too.

How can I access the record of specific staff which the user wants to view?

Comment: Kindly show us what you have done so far to achieve this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i assume you have a class that contains your staff
your vector would look like

```
vector<Staff> staff; // Staff would be replaced with your class name
```

then you can create a loop to populate your vector

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) // where n is the number of staff
{
staff.push_back(worker) // push back what ever function you have to to create a worker
}
```

then you can loop over your vector to print its content

```
  for (int i=0;i<staff.size();i++)
{ 
cout << staff[i].print() <<endl; // where print is a function in your class to print out the work
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But it is possible that each staff possesses the vector of record and prints the record from asking the user who want to know?

Comment: do you mean like the user inputs which worker they want to view?

Comment: Yes. The user can add and view the records of the specific staff .

Comment: yeah the way i would do it is for each worker give them an ID number, then the user inputs the ID they want to view. then use a loop to go over all your workers and check to see if your inputted ID equals the ID of one worker and if it does have a function that prints out the idea for a certain ID.

Comment: edit your post to include what you have so far so we can get an idea of what your doing

Comment: How about making a vector of record, which every staff has its own record? For example, print out the staff list to ask the user to choose. Then add records, like the title and date, to the vector. After that, the user can view the record of specific staff.

Comment: yes that would work, but you should create a class to create a staff record and to print a record. then yes it would work

Comment: Thank you. But how can I know which staff have or don't have record?

Comment: create a vector for each if the vector is empty for a staff then means they dont have a record